# How can I hide account information in a REST based service?

Tags: c#, android, wcf, web-services

I'm having security issues using a REST service to access a database to log users in, I have it working but I know it can't be like that because the password isn't encripted in any way and travelling through the URL. This is my code:

First, the code that sends the request:

```
private void validateUser(String user, String pass)
{

    String URL = "http://myserviceserver/MyService.svc";

    AlertDialog popup;

    try{
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL + "/Validate" + "/" + user + "/" + pass);

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        // Read response data into buffer
        char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        stream.close();

        String resultado = new String(buffer);

        if(resultado.contains("true"))
        {
            popup = createAlertDialog("Message", "User Validated", "OK");
            popup.show();
        }
        else
        {
            popup = createAlertDialog("Message", "User NOT Validated", "OK");
            popup.show();
        }       


    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }


}
```

Now, from the server side, this is my service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "Create/{user}/{pass}/{email}")]
    bool CreateNewAccount(string user, string pass, string email);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "Validate/{user}/{pass}")]
    bool ValidateUser(string user, string pass);
}
```

Now, this works like a charm, but is as insecure as it gets, but I don't quite understand how can I hide the sent information, because right now I'm login in by simply making a request at http://myserviceserver/MyService.svc/Validate/user/password.

Any help will be apreciated :)

Comment: Why don't you use the functions that are built into WCF for authentication? That way you won't have to reimplement a whole HTTP client with headers and stuff, just use WCF and configure it to use wsHttp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're worried about is man-in-the-middle attacks, I'd recommend HTTPS: certs are pretty cheap and most of those problems do go away if you use HTTPS.

If you're worried about leaking stuff in the server logs, well, I'd put the arguments as request parameters rather than part of the request. It looks like you're actually USING the username/password as arguments to your server methods, so HMACs won't entirely help you there. For the requests that are not using the parameters passed you may want to switch to a hash authentication scheme.

Comment: HMAC would  be used instead of passwords, not in addition to.  hmac signatures can be made public because they are of no use once the request has already been processed (or at a later date, when timestamps are part of the hashed cleartext)

Comment: Well, if you look at the actual method signatures above he is using the username/password to create the account (`bool CreateNewAccount(string user, string pass, string email);`). HMAC won't give him that, hence my hedging.

Answer (score 1):

one enlightened solution is to use HMAC authorization.  In this scheme, every request to your REST api includes an extra header that contains a checksum for the request itself, with the password or some other pre-shared key as part of the request.  The server, upon recieving the request, concatenates the request body with the password it keeps in its database and verifies that the checksums match.  This means that each request is stateless, and even if the request somehow gets sniffed, it won't be useful for an attacker since the checksum is only valid for that specific request.

A great example of this is the way Amazon Web Services works: [See here for a description](http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html)